# execFileSync running asyncronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization

we have a weird issue where for some developers the node.js execFileSync  function is running asynchronously and **NOT** synchronously the way that it is supposed to. We think this is being caused by some environmental difference between the machines that have the issue and those that do not but we have not been able to find the cause.
Has anyone ever experienced this before?

Here is a simple example. We have multiple calls to this block of code because we need to call some external scripts to perform some clean up in between runs but on the machines with the issue the code does not wait for the script to finish and return before continuing so the script could end up running multiple times at once instead of consecutively.

```
execFileSync(batchPath, {stdio:[0,1,2]}, function(error, stderr, stdout) {
       console.log(stderr);
       console.log(stdout);
       if (error !== null) {
           console.log('exec error: ', error);
       }
    });
```

Thanks for any ideas on what could cause this.

Comment: Why are you passing a callback for a *synchronous* method?

Comment: It's not my original code but so I can't say why that was done, I'm guessing that it might have been to try and handle the different outputs.

Comment: Well depending on what value has actually been assigned to `execFileSync`, you could actually be using `execFile`, which *is* asynchronous. The `*Sync` functions do not accept callbacks, they *return* the output instead.

Comment: Interesting point, I'll see if I can test that out, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See the docs for a correct invocation of `execFileSync`:

- https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.11.13/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfilesync_command_args_options

The arguments are 3:

1. the command (string)
2. list of command arguments (array)
3. options (object)

You are passing:

1. command (string)
2. options (object)
3. callback (function)

See how the `execFileSync` should be invoked and consider what are you trying to do.

How do you want to call a synchronous (blocking) function to run an external program (which by definition will let you do anything else only after that program finishes) and yet you want to communicate with that program while it's running (from a process that is blocked while that external program is running).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @rsp. The code is being used to run Postman tests and then call an external script to reset the database which is being stored in a docker container so this is why we need the synchronous function, to clarify the current code works as expected on most of out environments there are only a few that have my issue. Just to test your suggestion I tried the following but it still runs asynchronously:
var output = execFileSync(exePath, [testParam], {shell: true});